# Moving a file with rsync works at the command line, but not in cron

Tags: rsync

I'm working on a home automation system using a Raspberry Pi.  As part of this, I'd like the rPi to pull a file from my web server once a minute.  I've been using rsync, but I've run into an error I can't figure out.

This command works fine when run at the command line on my rPi:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress username@example.com:/home/user/example.com/cmd.txt /home/pi/sprinkler/input/cmd.txt
```

...but when it runs in cron, it produces this error in my log:

```
Unexpected local arg: /home/pi/sprinkler/input/
If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1375) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

...and I just answered my own question.  Extensive googling around didn't turn up an answer but I just tried putting my rsync command into a bash script, and running the script in cron instead of the command and now everything works!

I'll put this here in case anyone else stumbles over this issue.  Here's a script I called "sync.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash

# attempting a bash shell to use rsync to grab our file

rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
 --progress user@example.com:/home/user/example.com/vinhus/tovinhus
/cmd.txt /home/pi/sprinkler/input/
```

Comment: Add your cronjob to your question (no comment).

Comment: Would you edit your question to only have the question, and then create an actual answer with the answer? :) That's how Stack overflow works